# Determine whether or not H is a subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine whether or not H is a subgroup of G. (Assume that the operation of H is the same as that of G).

$$G=\langle\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},+\rangle, H=\{(x,y):y=2x\}$$

I am working on the closure under addition part and I just want to confirm something:

Let $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ be in $H$. Now is it $y=2x$ and $y'=2x$ or do I have to change the variable as well in $y'$ where $y'=2x'$?

So then:

$$(x,y)+(x',y')=(x+x',y+y')=(x+x',2x+2x') \text{ and } (x+x',2x+2x') \in H$$

I know I have to show that in order to be a subgroup it is not empty and that it has an inverse as well but I'm having trouble notation wise. I believe I have to say $y'=2x'$. Anyone can confirm?

Comment: You are correct that you have to use two different $x$s for $y$ and $y'$. If they were the same $x$, then they'd be the same $y$! As for inverses.. what is the *additive* inverse of $(x,2x)$? To show it is nonempty, just show that the identity element is in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not variables, they are elements: $(x,y)$ and $(x^{'},y^{'})$. So you chose two element which are satisfying the line equation: $x=2y$. If you say $a,b,a^{'},b^{'}$, this can be better and you wont confuse.